# Image Backgrounds in Activities

Tags: android, android-activity, background-image

I have an Activity that has a background image. Is there any difference in the heap usage of my application, if i set the image background in the XML file or if i obtain a reference of the layout and set the image from with my code.

Kind Regards

Comment: less code is easier to maintain

Comment: better to use in xml with top of layout

Comment: add background in xml and clear that background resources at destroy of an activity